# How to properly display incoming SMS sender and date?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver

I have the following code:

```
Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, 
        new String[] {"_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type"},
        null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cur);

String[] from = new String[]{"address", "body", "date"};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.sms_from, R.id.sms_body, R.id.sms_date};
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.sms_row, cur, from, to);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Currently I use `address` column to display SMS sender, so tel number is displayed. I would like to replace tel number with person name. I've expected that `person` contains it, but it is empty for majority of SMS. 
Then, `date` field contains `long` value, when I would like to show it in the format `DD.MM.YYYY`. I think I can override `setViewValue()` to fix it. But is there any other (better) solution&

How could I fix these two problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the date issue you can do this

```
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    formatter.format( Long.parseLong( dateString ) );
```

and for sender name, try this

```
    Cursor cs= context.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},condition,null,null);  
    cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

Comment: Thanks. Your reply doesn't answer my question fully. So, I've done what I need with `setViewValue()`, but your reply helped, so I accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think `person` is empty for numbers that don´t exist in contacts.

For the date:

```
String strDateTime = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm", new Date(longValue));
```

Comment: `person` is empty for almost all SMS. Don't I need to have some additional permissions to use it?

Comment: I don´t know try: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>`

Answer (score -1):

Try this method to show proper date and time in sms. In this you need to pass the date you you receive from cursor

```
public String changeDate(long date) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        Date dt = new Date(date);
        Date now = new Date();
        dt.setTime(date);

        if (now.getYear()==dt.getYear() && now.getMonth()==dt.getMonth() && now.getDate()==dt.getDate())
            sdf.applyPattern("h:mm a");
        else if (now.getYear()==dt.getYear())
            sdf.applyPattern("d MMM" + " " + "h:mm a");
        else
            sdf.applyPattern("d MMM yyyy" + " " + "h:mm a");

        return sdf.format(dt);
    }
```